# Quarkus custom banner configure does not working

Tags: quarkus

#### Describe the bug

Hi guys,

I've read [the document](https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started#banner)  and here is my banner:

[Banner image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/22415582/228731603-7ac70fb4-2f20-4c74-9333-8c9cbb72fb35.png)

and here is my application.properties

`quarkus.banner.enabled=true`

`quarkus.banner.path=default_banner11.txt`

and here is my log. Banner was not loaded

[log](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/22415582/228731781-8db232f8-5eb0-4ccc-8291-77e6a3ad6ce5.png)

As in spring, I only just add a file named banner.txt in `src/main/resources`, it'll displayed.

Please help me to fix this. I want to have different banner in each of my project.

Thanks and have a nice day guys!

#### Expected behavior

Display my custom banner

#### Actual behavior

When I put `quarkus.banner.path=default_banner11.txt` in application.properties, there isn't any banner displayed

#### How to Reproduce?

1. Add a file .txt in src/main/resources
2. Add two config in application.properties
   `quarkus.banner.enabled=true`
   `quarkus.banner.path=default_banner11.txt`
3. Run project

#### Output of `java -version`

java 11.0.17 2022-10-18 LTS

#### Quarkus version or git rev

2.16.5.Final

#### Build tool (ie. output of `mvnw --version` or `gradlew --version`)

Apache Maven 3.9.1 (2e178502fcdbffc201671fb2537d0cb4b4cc58f8)

Comment: If the banner is expected while running test, I am assuming that you need to place a copy of both `application.properties` and `default_banner11.txt` files in path `src/test/resources`.

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the same problem in my project...
I created 2 banners using https://patorjk.com/software/taag/

- 'Bloody' font for banner one
- 'Ogre' font for banner two

and the former banner doesn't show up but the latter is correctly showed.
Change your banner using a different set of characters and the problem should gone.

Comment: I created new project and it worked